# Fiware IOTagent JSON creates a big log file

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

The IOTAgent JSON is creating a very big log file, with the messages sent to the Orion Context Broker. Is it possible to configure in this nodejs process some rules for log management, maximun size, rotation, compression, log level messages. How to do ?

Many thanks in advance for your support

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact cause of the problem, but you could consider the following hints:

- Use ERROR or WARNING (*) as `logLevel` field in `config.js`. Levels INFO or DEBUG are very verbose.
- You can use [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) to rotate logs. Log rotate is a general purpose tool which many documentation around, so it should be easy to master (with time to learn, of course ;). The following configuration files in the IOTA-JSON repo may help:

  - [logrotate configuration](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-json/blob/master/rpm/SOURCES/etc/logrotate.d/logrotate-iotajson.conf)
  - [crontab configuration to invoke logrotate](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-json/blob/master/rpm/SOURCES/etc/cron.d/cron-logrotate-iotajson-size)

(*) I don't remember if the right config token is WARNING or WARN (or both!), you would need to test, sorry...

Comment: The IOTagent receives data from real devices, and the _LogLevel_ by default is defined in the file as DEBUG. I have changed to ERROR, I hope this will solve this issue, anyway I will try implement the logrotate as soon as I can. I will inform you about that also. Many thanks for your comment

Comment: Thanks @fgalan!!, I have edited the _config.js_ with the level ERROR and I have included in file _/etc/logrotate.conf_ the following content `/var/log/iotagent.log 
{
      daily
      rotate 7
      copytruncate
      compress
      notifempty
      missingok
}`,  the log file of iotagent.log only gets ERROR messages (Mongo alarms) and it is compressed and rotated . ;-)